# XSLT Exception - NaN while generating excel

Tags: xslt

I am trying to merge columns with the parameter values as below is my xslt

```
    enter  <Cell ss:MergeAcross="$totalSelectedColumn + 2" ss:StyleID="sHeader">
                <Data ss:Type="String">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat($worksheetName, ' - COMPARISON REPORT - Discrepancies and Validations')" />
                </Data>
              </Cell>


<xsl:if test="$isAMLrequired=1">
              <Cell ss:MergeAcross="{$totalSelectedItemBomAttrColumn}" ss:StyleID="{$rowStyle01}" />
            </xsl:if>
```

I am passing value in aspx file(Dictionary) as follows

```
 args.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("totalSelectedItemBomAttrCol", (selectedItemAndBomAttributeList.Distinct().Count() <= 0 ? 0 : selectedItemAndBomAttributeList.Distinct().Count() - 1).ToString()));

            args.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("totalSelectedCol", selectedAttributeList.Distinct().Count().ToString()));
```

After downloading excel, i am getting below exception.

> XML ERROR in Table
>   REASON: Bad Value
>   FILE:   C:\Users\gssmrose\Downloads\BaaN_ROOT_110918 (10).xls
>   GROUP:  Row
>   TAG:    Cell
>   ATTRIB: MergeAcross
>   VALUE:  NaN

i debugged the program and the value is a number and i am not sure why this exception is coming while downloading file. Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: It's possibly because you need to use "Attribute Value Templates" in your ss:MergeAcross attribute. It should be `<Cell ss:MergeAcross="{$totalSelectedColumn + 2}" />`

Comment: even i tried that too. but it is not working :(

Comment: If you open the produced file in Notepad, what value do you see in the `ss:MergeAcross` attribute?

Comment: It is showing NaN only. I am passing count of list( int totalSelectedColumnCount = Convert.ToInt32(selectedAttributeList.Distinct().Count());) in a dictionary<string, string>. Can you advise on this?

Comment: It looks like your parameters are not being passed correctly to the xslt. You might need to edit your question to show more of your code.

Comment: Thanks tim. let me check once